# Specify onClick for a Point of a Pointcloud in react-three-fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I am working on a project in react-three-fiber where I have to bring a large number of points to the screen. To do this, I am using a <Points> tag like so:

```
const PointCloud = props => {
  const vertexSize = 0.05;
  const CircleImg = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, circleImg);


  const onClick = (event, position) => {
    console.log(position)
  }

  return (
    <Points>
      <pointsMaterial attach={"material"}
        map={CircleImg}
        size={vertexSize}
        transparent={false}
        alphaTest={0.5}
        opacity={1.0}
        sizeAttenuation />

      {props.positions.map((pos, i) => {
        return <Point key={i} position={pos} onClick={e => onClick(e, pos)} />
      })}
    </Points >
  )
};
```

I would like it so that when a point is clicked, that point, and *only* that point, logs its coordinates to the console.

However, in the code above *every* point in the whole scene logs its location whenever one is clicked.
How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

I uploaded an mvp of the problem the a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/finia2NA/threeproblem/main)

---

I have tried checking the distanceTo property of the event, but it does not seem to straightforwardly convey the distance of the ray to the point like

distanceTo < vertexSize/2 ==> interesection

like I had hoped.

I also tried an implementation with sprites, which worked in principle, but when rendering a very large number of points the performance of this method is too worse to use.